# Activate more than one id jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to have more than one div id to start this animation. Why is this not working?

I mean this:

```
$("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {
    anim10();
});
```

Here is the Full Code

```
 /** ANIMATE DropDown  */
var $a = $("#navigation"),
$b = $(".mainNavitem:eq(1)"),
$c = $(".c");

function anim1() {
$b.animate({width: 395}, {duration: 300, complete: anim2});
}

function anim2() {
$a.animate({top:"70px"}, {duration: 400});
$c.animate({top:"70px"}, {duration: 400});
}

$("#mains").click(function() {
anim1();
});

function anim10() {
$c.animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 200});
$a.animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 200 , complete: anim20});
}

function anim20() {
$b.animate({width: 80}, {duration: 200});
}

$("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {
anim10();
});
```

Do you have any Idea how I can fix this?

**EDIT:**

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4jyq/2/)

Comment: how you defined a/c? does any of the animations work?

Comment: What are your `$a`, `$b` and `$c` variables referring to ? Global scope ?

Comment: Just a moment i will edit it

Comment: The actual multiple selection syntax looks fine to me, here is the ref: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/, you could try and give all 3 elements a common class instead, and add the click handler to that. Also if you put a 'console.log("something")' in side the click handler, alongside anim10() you will be able to see if the click event handler is working or if it is just anim10() that fails.

Comment: Is it just `anim10()` that is not working?  Does `anim20()` work?  Make sure those elements are appropriately positioned, using either `absolute` or `relative`.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: also did you add your script in a dom ready handler / whether any of these elements are dynamic

Comment: i simply want to activate anim10() on more than one div... only one div starts anim10()

Comment: The multiple selection works as you are using it. Are you sure the HTML is correct and uses the correct Ids? Post the HTML to the Fiddle so that we can have a look.

Comment: Wait, do you mean that you want them all to animate when you click any single one? http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Show us your `HTML` also

Comment: Hey i don't now what the problem was but now it's working... i loaded my website up again and now it' working! Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: and there was no error in my browser :) i don't know but its fixed now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running your code with $(document).ready() event? like

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("#mains").click(function() {
        anim1();
    });

    $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {
        anim10();
    });
})
```